Switch router doesnt work with Security in OKTA React V17
<Security
           oktaAuth={oktaAuth}
           onAuthRequired={customAuthHandler}
           restoreOriginalUri={restoreOriginalUri}
           >
              <Switch>
                 <Route path="/" component={SignIn} />
                 <Route path="/login" component={SignIn} />
                 <Route path="/login/callback" component={LoginCallback} />
                 <PrivateRoute  exact={true}  path={RouteCodes.Home} component={HomeComponent} />
                 <PrivateRoute exact path={RouteCodes.Help} component={HelpComponent} />
              </Switch>
        </Security>

After including Switch inside Security, the page doesnt load. It works fine when we remove Switch.
